# React Rerun an animation every time a string update

Tags: reactjs, css-animations

I would like to create a React component which takes a string rerun an animation every time a char has changed on the string.
But I would like to run the animation only on updated chars.

I Ended up with this code, but the animation is rerun only one times on two and I can't see what is the issue.

```
interface AnimatedStringProps {
  string: string;
}

interface AnimatedStringChar {
  char: string;
  update: boolean;
}

export function AnimatedString({ string }: AnimatedStringProps) {
  const [chars, setChars] = useState<AnimatedStringChar[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newstring = string.split('');
    if (newstring.length !== chars.length) setChars(newstring.map((char) => ({ char, update: false })));
    else {
      console.log('DBG', chars);
      for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (newstring[i] !== chars[i].char) chars[i].update = true;
        else chars[i].update = false;
        chars[i].char = newstring[i];
        setChars(chars);
      }
    }
  }, [string]);

  const handleAnimationEnd = (index: number) => {
    console.log('Handle animation end', index);
    chars[index].update = false;
    setChars(chars);
  };

  return (
    <div className="AnimatedString">
      {chars.map(({ char, update }, index) => (
        <span
          key={index}
          className={classNames('AnimatedString__Char', 'animate__animated', {
            animate__fadeIn: update,
          })}
          onAnimationEnd={() => handleAnimationEnd(index)}
        >
          {char}
        </span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

.AnimatedString__Char {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 1ch;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

And I use the component by passing it a stat updated every 5seconds

```
function UseComponent {
  const [test, setTest] = useState<string>('Hello 000 world');
  let count = 0;
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      count++;
      setTest(`Hello ${count.toString().padStart(3, '0')} world`);
    }, 5000);
  }, []);
  return (<div><AnimatedString string={test} /></div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, changing the key in the map allow to force react to rerender and so to rerun animation.

So I just had to set the key to a combination of index and char to allow automatic rerender when a char has changed at an index.

Working solution

```
export function AnimatedString({ string }: AnimatedStringProps) {
  const [chars, setChars] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setChars(string.split(''));
  }, [string]);

  return (
    <div className="AnimatedString">
      {chars.map((char, index) => (
        <span
          key={`${index}_${char}`}
          className={classNames('AnimatedString__Char', 'animate__animated', 'animate__bounceIn')}
        >
          {char}
        </span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```